# Send native HTTP request from Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, http

I am not that familiar with native Android development, I have some experience in Web development

I am trying create a hybrid android app using Cordova, I know how to send an AJAX request but you can not send that http requests to all website, becuase orgin policy, but the native Java can send that kind of HTTP request

I saw lot of people creating plugins that makes native API available to JavaScript, so is there any plugin in cordova that can send http request without the problem of origin policy?

Comment: it doesn't matter request is from webview or native eventually both requests will be same but still if you want to check then you can check this plugin https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/blob/master/README.md

Comment: What you mean by the request are same, does cordova web view doesn't have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problem? for example if I want to get google home page html content

Comment: From so many years we havn't faced any issue for http requests. if you are facing issue with specific API then please let me know the API then maybe i can look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes exists, and works very well, we are using on our project the plugin [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http), based on [cordova-HTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/blob/master/README.md).

The project is a onsen/angularjs/cordova, and the plugin work without CORS errors, normal :), now we are evaluating if is more efficient native HTTP calls or javascript HTTP calls, the author of the plugin cite three good motivations to change for native calls:

```
Background threading - all requests are done in a background thread.
Handling of HTTP code 401 - read more at Issue CB-2415.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415
SSL Pinning - read more at LumberBlog.
http://blog.lumberlabs.com/2012/04/why-app-developers-should-care-about.html
```

The plugin offer a good documentation, and is easy to use with simple `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` and `GET` methods. Is possible set Headers and another presets.